# Good tips for first-time Power Grid players?

Tags: power-grid

**Disclaimer:** I know there's already been some discussion on this topic, but I'm going to ask the question anyway because I've never played the game before, and thus, have yet to use my copy of Power Grid in the context of actually playing the game.

What are some general tips for people who have *never played before* to get started and have an actual idea of what they're doing in Power Grid? Also, what are some tips for explaining the game to people who have also never played the game before?

P.S. Sorry if this question seems like it's been asked before (and thus, horribly redundant), and altogether a dumb question

Comment: Do you feel that [this older question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/591/beginner-power-grid-strategy?rq=1) doesn't answer your question? If so, you might want to clarify what you're asking that's different than what it asks.

Comment: I was thinking that the difference would be in having some of the more complicated aspects of the game being explained to me so that I can take less time learning how to play the first time I play the game

Comment: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/81071/how-to-lose-at-power-grid-funkenschlag

Comment: that appears to be for an online version of the game

Comment: This question isn't how to best strategy to win but best way to **teach** the game rules.  I found the best way is play practice round or 2 with someone that know how to play the game.  If you don't have that luxury, and are teaching yourself I found videos ( [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjA6pawLGxg) ) to be the most helpful to get overview of game play.  Once you understand the flow you can consult the rule book for the finer details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The other question is about beginner tactics so do read that, however I'll cover a couple of common confusions for first timers*

1. Board regions (in the base game) have no meaning other than to decide the size of the playing area.  The rules describe setting up as having one area per player.  That should be read as "if you have three players use a 3-area-sized playing area" **not** "Albert has the red area, Bert has blue, Charlie has green,..."
2. You have to build additional houses in a way that is connected to your network.  That does **not** mean they have to be *adjacent*.  You *can* build *anywhere* but to do so you have to pay the connection cost across to your existing network. Unlike in Settlers, you *can* build through others' houses; but, boy, is it expensive.
3. "Turn Order" can be confusing.  The order as indicated by the order of markers on the line is only used once per round, most of the time the order is the *reverse* of that.

(1a. On some expansion boards particular areas affect the play, for example you can't build nuclear if you're *only* in Eire on the UK map or Denmark on the Europe map, etc.)